# ZonedDateTime in MongoDB through Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, java-8, morphia, zoneddatetime

In a nutshell:

- `java.time.ZonedDateTime` has no args constructor (actually it has no
  constructor at all)
- to get over this, I should write a `ZonedDateTimeConverter` for Morphia
- if I try to save and load my `ZonedDateTime` without converter, Morphia
  saves the full `ZonedDateTime` object as `DBObject` which is cool because
  I could read all the fields and initiate a ZonedDateTime object from
  it, but I got an exception on loading: `No usable constructor for java.time.ZonedDateTime`
- if I try to save and load the `ZonedDateTime` with the converter, I got
  another exception: `Can't find a codec for class java.time.LocalDateTime`. I started to play with the converters, based
  on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569228/mongodb-bson-codec-not-being-used-while-encoding-object) article but without any result.
- So if I have no converter I can save but can't load, if I have the converter, I can't even save because of missing codecs.

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**
Turned out that I should write a converter for each subtype started from `ZonedDateTime` (e.g. `LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`), but turned out that I should write a converter for `java.time.ZoneRegion` which is package-private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pushed support for the more common Java 8 datetime types to Morphia last week targeting the 1.3 release.  See the issue [here](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/940) and the linked commits.  If there's a type you need that's not listed, please file a Morphia issue and I'll try to make sure it's included in 1.3 as well.

Comment: I imagine this is a popular use case, but if we want to lock down to a particular instant in time and be immune to daylight savings or different server timezones, it looks like the java8 way of doing things is this ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)? How should we be using this with morphia so that it is storable and serial/deserializable?