# Query by date in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I was going to get distinct values form collection. 
I stored time as follows:

```
"time" : ISODate("2017-01-26T09:46:26.523Z")
```

`new ISO8601DateFormat()` is not working, that gives me below error

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find
>   a codec for class
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat.

My code is looks like below.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("user_id").is(id).and("time").gt(new ISO8601DateFormat()));
mongoTemplate.getCollection("user_log").distinct("timezone", query.getQueryObject())
```

My mongodb terminal command is follows and it works perfectly.

```
db.user_log.find({ "user_id" : "1" , "time" : { "$gt" : new ISODate("2017-01-25T00:16:15.184Z")}})
```

What is correct way to approach when I access from java?

Comment: Maybe helpful link for You: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569228/mongodb-bson-codec-not-being-used-while-encoding-object

Comment: What is your java version ?

Comment: @Veeram java 8 and spring boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2017-01-25T00:16:15.184Z"); 
Date time = Date.from(instant);
```

Replace your time criteria with below

```
and("time").gt(time)
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Can I request another help? If yes, How do I easily subtract 24 hours form that date format?

Comment: You're welcome. Something like `instant = instant.minus(1,ChronoUnit.DAYS);`

Comment: @vikram how do I get currnet datetime like this format "2017-01-25T00:16:15.184Z" easily? is new ISO8601DateFormat() correct?

Comment: Instant instant = Instant.parse("2017-01-25T00:16:15.184Z"); to insert here

Comment: No. that was just an example. How does your  input date looks like ? Use Instant objects directly across your application.

Comment: I want to get current localdate and time under that format?

Comment: just use `Instant instant = Instant.now()` to get current date time

Comment: that what i want. But it gives utc time. How do i get local time?. Do i have to add?

Comment: `LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());` Take a look at Java 8 datetime api to know more.